# Disk I/O overload on a particular node in HPC

Tags: debian

How to solve the problem of a HPC: when disk I/O gets overloaded on a particular node of HPC
The problem is : OS spends significant time waiting for I/O (input/output) operations. It could be indicator of performance issues with storage system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a linux debian cluster where a particular node is being affected by  disk i/o overload. how to fix that?